# hml5 toDataUrl() not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I do this:

```
$('#displayBtn').click(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("textArea").value = dataUrl;
});
```

It works great on Firefox and IE, but no luck with Chrome. I googled and came back with the issue relating to .SVG files, but I'm not using any SVG files, only PNG and JPG. Here is a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ykpCn/2/
Is it because I'm using transparent PNGs? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Very new to HTML5, I hope it's not something stupid that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to Cross origin resource access. The image you have rendered on the canvas is from a different origin (http://moosepi.com). You can't call toDataURL() on images which are from different origins.

If you fire up your Chrome developer tools, you will find this in your console. "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18". This is the expected behavior as per the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

Solution:
1. Host the images from your server (may be using a Proxy setup).
2. Set [CORS](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#cors-settings-attribute) attribute on the resource. Remember the source must set the appropriate headers.

Comment: Thanks so much! this was exactly my problem! also... I didn't know about chrome developer tools, just like firebug.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently that ONLY works on Chrome if it's being hosted on a webserver? It works fine if I upload to the server and then view it from there, but will not work locally. My question is stupid now. Sorry for wasting time.

Comment: Your question is not stupid at all... I just wasted half a day on this because Chrome is a dinky browser... it is not a small issue,, you should not have to test in live environment to get things to work.