# Getting error "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' " in google chrome only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-chrome

I want to capture the street view of the google map using the `html2canvas` but i am getting the following error:

> "Uncaught Security Error: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported."

This error is only occur in google chrome only.

```
html2canvas($("#map"), {
 useCORS: true,
 onrendered: function(canvas) {
 var mapsourceUrl = canvas.toDataURL();//here i am getting the error
 });
```

Comment: I'm surprised this only happens in Chrome to be honest

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456745/hml5-todataurl-not-working-on-chrome) maybe can help you

Comment: the useCORS flag means it attempts to use CORS before reverting to proxy - perhaps chrome is fooling html2canvas into thinking the CORS request worked (even though it wont) - what happens if you set useCORS: false?

Comment: When i am using userCors :false its showing same error